# Programming in Haskell book's some code not working

Tags: haskell, command-line

I'm on the chapter 9.6 of book `Programming in Haskell`, page 91. The function `writeat` is supposed to write given string on given location on the command prompt but this is not working for me.

```
type Pos = (Int, Int)

goto        :: Pos -> IO ()
goto (x, y) = putStr ("\ESC[" ++ show y ++ ";" ++ show x ++ "H")

writeat     :: Pos -> String -> IO ()
writeat p xs = do
    goto p
    putStr xs
```

But it is not doing what the book says. Is it because I'm on Windows? If so is there a workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's because you are on windows. Those are ANSI escape sequences, and Windows doesn't support them: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Windows_and_DOS

You can possibly work around this by using cygwin with mintty, and making sure your TERM is set to one that support ANSI; or run your haskell in a linux VM, using an xterm (like this VM from fpcomplete: https://www.fpcomplete.com/page/haskell-eval-vm) . But it's not worth all that effort for this example.

Comment: this part of code is gonna be used to display calculator inside terminal. i guess i should dual boot install some linux distro.

Comment: Note that the `ansi-terminal` package lets you do text colouring, etc in a portable way on both Windows and Unix. I love that.